# Is there any way to make a dreadnought a character OUTSIDE of iron hands

Tags: warhammer-40k

I play a custom Dark Angels successor chapter, whose chapter master is entombed in a leviathan dreadnought, and I am wondering if there is a way outside of the iron hands stratagem as I would like him to be the warlord and take appropriate warlord traits.